# How to use shortcode in js url

Tags: shortcode

Here's the code I'm trying to use.

```
<input type="button" class="next-step" value="Adopt Now" onClick="parent.location='http://example.com/adoption-application/?Name=[Title]'" />
```

The shortcode Title is defined.

End link in browser shows as http://example.com/adoption-application/?Name=[Title]

Should show as

http://example.com/adoption-application/?Name=Skeeter (or whatever the current value of [Title] is)

What am I missing to make this work?

Comment: You need to specify where you are intending to use this code or you will not get an answer you can use.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use a shortcode inside an attribute. You need to make a shortcode that will output the whole element.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I need [Title] to be dynamic (it's the title of the page). I guess a better question would be "how do I make it possible to enter a shortcode inside an attribute?" :)

Comment: You can not use a shortcode inside an attribute, and you should not. This proved to be a vectore for many security problems.

Comment: maybe I should have asked first where exctly this snippet is being placed, in the editor or template file?

Answer (score 0):

You are using inline JavaScript, so it'll be fine to render shortcode like this;

```
<input type="button" class="next-step" value="Adopt Now" onClick="parent.location='http://example.com/adoption-application/?Name=<?php echo do_shortcode('[Title]'); ?>'" />
```

Comment: `do_shortcode` should not be used like this. Shortcodes simply execute a callback function with the provided arguments and content. If you want to execute that callback function in PHP, just call it directly (eg. `the_shortcode_callback()` instead of `do_shortcode('[the_shortcode]')`). Don't bother with the regex and other stuff that `do_shortcode` includes.

Comment: Why not? Performance issues? Security? The question is about rendering shortcode in an inline JavaScript code. So this is a valid answer. We don't know the evironment, we don't know how many times this code will be called. I don't assumed anything, I just answered the question. Maybe he need everything that `do_shortcode` function does. How could we know?

Comment: Unfortunately, where I'm using it won't accept php. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you're entering this directly in the post editor, rather than have the Shortcode return the title, make a Shortcode to return the link with title.

```
function adoption_link_function(){
    global $post;
    $link = "parent.location='http://example.com/adoption-application/?Name={$post->post_title}'";
    return '<input type="button" class="next-step" value="Adopt Now" onClick="' . $link . '" />';
}
add_shortcode( 'adoption_link', 'adoption_link_function' );
```